# join without forgetting data that wasn't affected by the join

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have three tables I'm interested in, here's the relevant information:

```
+---------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+
| Class         | | Tests         | | StudentClasses| | Student       |
+---------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+
| ClassID       | | ClassID       | | ClassID       | | StudentID     |
|               | | WholeYearTest | | StudentID     | | StudentYear   |
|               | | TestYear      | |               | |               |
+---------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+
```

I have a variable `login`, which is a `Student`.

I am running this query in LINQ:

```
        from tests in App.db.Tests
        join studentClasses in App.db.StudentClasses on tests.ClassID equals studentClasses.ClassID
        where (
         (tests.WholeYearTest == true && tests.TestYear == login.StudentYear)
         || 
         studentClasses.StudentID == login.StudentID
        )
        select tests;
```

Unfortunately, I'm only getting results which correspond to the condition `studentClasses.StudentID == login.StudentID`

What I want:

- All tests that the student has to sit due to `StudentYear` being equal to `TestYear` and `WholeYearTest` being true
- All tests that the student has to sit because one of the possibly multiple `StudentClasses` associated with them is listed under `Tests.ClassID`.

I think ***it's probably due to a blatant misunderstanding of how JOIN works***, but I can't think of any other way to implement this. Can anyone put forward an implementation suggestion other than looping all tests? If not, I suppose I'll use a loop, but I'm sure there must be some way of implementing this in LINQ.

Comment: Is it possible to have a Student class without a test? Because if your second condition only appears in cases when the class has no test you will never get those records. Join will drop those records from the result set.

Comment: A test can either be for the entire year (I.e. year 6) or a specific class, dictated by tests.TestYear. Is there any way to stop join dropping those records?

Comment: I ideally want to select tests that are caused by being a whole year test for the student's year, or applies to any of the student's classes in specific.

Comment: The purpose of Join is in fact to drop those records :)

Comment: Is there any way at all I can do what I want to do through LINQ then? I just wanted to use join to bring another table into the equation just to test for class relations for the student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
from tests in App.db.Tests
join studentClasses in App.db.StudentClasses
on new { tests.ClassID, login.StudentID }
equals new { studentClasses.ClassID, studentClasses.StudentID }
into gj
from subStudentClass in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
where (
 (tests.WholeYearTest == true && tests.TestYear == login.StudentYear)
 || 
 (subStudentClass != null && subStudentClass.StudentID == login.StudentID)
)
select tests
```

The biggest difference is that there is now an [outer join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) so that you can still find results where the join fails.

Also, the join is now by both `ClassID` and `StudentID`, so that you won't get matches for other students.

With the following test data:

```
var App = new { db = new {
    Tests = new[] {
        new Test { ClassID = 1, WholeYearTest = true, TestYear = 1999 },
        new Test { ClassID = 2, WholeYearTest = true, TestYear = 1999 },
        new Test { ClassID = 3, WholeYearTest = false, TestYear = 1999 },
        new Test { ClassID = 4, WholeYearTest = false, TestYear = 1999 },
    },
    StudentClasses = new[] {
        new StudentClass { ClassID = 1, StudentID = 1 },
        new StudentClass { ClassID = 1, StudentID = 2 },
        new StudentClass { ClassID = 4, StudentID = 1 },
        new StudentClass { ClassID = 3, StudentID = 2 },
    }
} };
var login = new { StudentID = 1, StudentYear = 1999 };

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, (
    //above query
  ).Select(x => string.Join(",", x.ClassID, x.WholeYearTest, x.TestYear))));
```

It prints

```
1,True,1999 
2,True,1999 
4,False,1999
```

Comment: It's highlighting 'join' and giving the error: "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'." Any idea what's happening with that? And thanks so much for the help! I've always been terrible at database querying beyond the basics, it's totally beyond me :P

Comment: I think that your property names and/or types don't match. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563208/linq-to-sql-join-issues for how to specify property names in the anonymous type there.

Comment: Ah; I appended .Value onto the int? value, and set property names for them, and it seems to be working perfectly! Thanks very much for this, would've been stuck here all week.

Answer (score 1):

A single inner join is not sufficient; your query actually needs to be executed with an inner join AND a union.

Give this a try - I didn't test it out because I figure you can do that :)

Note - you may need to insert a Distinct() in there as well.

```
var q1 = (from tests in App.db.Tests
          join studentClasses in App.db.StudentClasses 
             on tests.ClassID equals studentClasses.ClassID
          select tests).Concat(App.db.Tests.Where(t=>t.WholeYearTest && t.TestYear == login.StudentYear));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to accept Tim S.'s as he answered first, but thank you all the same, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Just FYI, while I think Tim's answer was awesome, and definitely deserves kudos for the extra mile of making the tests, I also think the simplest solution should be used that gets the job done. Sooner or later you will have to edit the code, and you want to be able to read it. :)