# How to do a left outer join with linq and many to many table?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-migrations, fluent

When I tried to do a left outer join with MVC code first C#, I got this error:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.

I need help to understand why the join clause is wrong. Here is the code:

```
return (from t in context.Tenders
                    join c in context.Contacts on t.Contacts equals c.Tenders into leftOuter
                    from subpet in leftOuter.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    orderby t.id
                    where (c.Email == currentUserProfile.Email || c.UserProfileId == currentUserProfile.Id || t.UserProfileId == currentUserProfile.Id) && t.EndDate > now
                                         && t.IsClosed == false
                                         && t.IsCancel == false
                    select t).Union(
                    from t in context.Tenders
                    where t.EndDate > now
                    && t.IsClosed == false
                    && t.IsCancel == false
                    && t.PrivacyLevelId == 1
                    select t).Count();
```

Fluent API:

```
// Many to many Tender => Contact
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tender>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Contacts)
            .WithMany(t => t.Tenders)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("TenderId")
                 .MapRightKey("ContactId")
                 .ToTable("ContactTender"));
```

Comment: Can you provide table schema info with joins?  Have you seen this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563208/linq-to-sql-join-issues